# Querying postgresql using sequelize ORM for an nested JSONB object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

This is how the JSONB looks into the database

```
matrix:{
  toolsMethodsOther:{
    networking: [],
    testing: {
      testingGeneric: [],
      testingTools: []
    },
    developmentTools: [],
    developmentDesignTehniques: [],
    developmentOnSpecificAreas: [],
    serverAdministration: {
      administration: [],
      microsoftProject: []
    },
    managementLeadership: [],
    developmentMethodologies: [],
    industryExperience: []
  }

}
```

This is how an item from an array looks like:

```
item:{
  item: "Test item",
  year: 2016,
  skill: 4,
  lastYear: 2014
}
```

Let's say that i want to get all rows WHERE toolsMethodsOther-> networking contains an object of this form:

```
item:{
  item: {
    $like: "Test"
  },
  year: 2016,
  skill: 4,
  lastYear: 2014
}
```

Can you guys point me into the right direction? I've read their documentation about querying JSONB but has no success in getting any results other than an emptry result with 0 rows. Also, google did not help with much ...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The example is for **multiple WHERE** clause with regular columns combined with JSONB field matches.

**Try this:**

```
where:{
  field1: 'value1',
  field2: 'value2',
  $and:[
   Sequelize.where(
        Sequelize.literal('"tableName"."jsonbColumn"->>\'keyInsideJSONB\''),
        valueWhichYouWantToMatch
   ),
   Sequelize.where(
        Sequelize.literal('"tableName"."jsonbColumn"->"nestedJsonKey"->>\'keyInsideNestedJSONBKey\''),
        nestedValueWhichYouWantToMatch
   )
 ]
}
```

Hope it helps.